# How to make a Django server portable?

Tags: django, portability

My web server depends on nginx, django, and a lot of python dependencies. I'm wondering if there is a way to create a portable image/script that I can run in a new server and quickly get it up and running.
Is Docker relevant to this?

Comment: why not using git

Comment: Docker is definitely relevant to this, but beyond the scope of an SO answer - take a look [at this guide](http://ruddra.com/2016/08/14/docker-django-nginx-postgres/)

Comment: You can use git + ansible combo

Comment: docker  is what you need

Answer (score -1):

You should **always** use git to manage your code. With git you could get your django project in the other server quickly. But just that.

Also you have to migrate your database. Every DB engine have dump options for doing this.

Do not forget to move your static assests.  Probably, you've all of them in one directory.

What about your nginx, database installation and configuration? Here is relevant Docker.

With all of this, you should migrate successfully.